# How to add gridlines to mesh3d in plotly R

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, visualization

I can not add a wireframe appearance to mesh3d plots (gridlines on x and y axes) using the plotly package in R.

The `contours = list(y = list(show = TRUE), x = list(show = TRUE))` argument from plotly's surface plot doesn't work when making a mesh3d plot (see my example code). I'd like to use a mesh3d plot instead of a surface plot because it is easier to keep track of x and y variables.

Example with reproducible data

```
library(plotly)
library(viridis)

# Define the data
df1 <-data.frame(
  v1 = c(7000, 13000, 19000, 25000, 7000, 13000, 19000, 25000, 7000, 13000, 19000, 25000, 7000, 13000, 19000, 25000),
  v2 = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 66, 66, 66, 66, 178, 178, 178, 178, 312, 312, 312, 312),
  v3 = c(1200.123, 2500.567, 2400.789, 2300.456, 1650.789, 3700.123, 4200.345, 4300.567, 3300.456, 4000.789, 6800.123, 7810.345, 2300.789, 4200.567, 4900.123, 5200.567))


#Surface plot - nice gridlines on x and y axes
Matrix <- xtabs(df1$v3 ~ df1$v1 + df1$v2)

plot_ly(z=~Matrix,
        type = "surface", opacity = .45,
        contours = list(y = list(show = TRUE),
                        x = list(show = TRUE)))
```

Surface plot output with plotly

[image: Surface plot output with plotly]

```
#mesh3d plot - no gridlines, the contours argument does not work!
plot_ly(z = df1$v3, x = df1$v1, y = df1$v2,
        type = "mesh3d", opacity = .45,
        colorscale = "Viridis", intensity = df1$v3,
        contours = list(y = list(show = TRUE),
                        x = list(show = TRUE)))
```

mesh3d plot output with plotly

[image]

Answer (score 3):

---

There isn't an argument in Plotly that will give you what you're looking for. You can manually add the lines though.

For example, you could just plot the line segments from each set of points from your data.

```
# your plot as depicted in your question
plt <- plot_ly(data = df1, z = ~v3, x = ~v1, y = ~v2, type = "mesh3d", opacity = .45,
               intensity = ~v3)
# the traces for the lines
map2(1:2, 2:1, \(j, k) { 
  plt <<- plt %>%                # add lines for x rows, then add lines for y rows
    add_trace(inherit = F, type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines", 
              data = group2NA(df1, names(df3)[j], ordered = names(df1)[k]), # make them segments
              x = ~v1, y = ~v2, z = ~v3, line = list(color = "black"), showlegend = F)
})

plt %>% colorbar(title = "v3") # fix the colorbar title
```

[image]

If you wanted your mesh to have more x-y gridlines, depicting more detail, you could use the midpoint of each set of points within each line of each x and y group.

```
# your plot as depicted in your question
plt <- plot_ly(data = df1, z = ~v3, x = ~v1, y = ~v2, type = "mesh3d", opacity = .45,
               intensity = ~v3)

# collect line segment midpoints
df3 <- df1
map2(1:2, 2:1, \(j, k) {                # midpoints for x rows, then for y rows
  d1 <- group2NA(df3, names(df3)[j], ordered = names(df3)[k])  # NAs split line segments
  map(1:(nrow(d1) - 1), \(l) {                                 # for each group of 2 rows
    mps <- d1[l:(l + 1), ] %>% map(., mean) %>% unlist()       # find midpoint
    df3 <<- bind_rows(df3, mps) %>% filter(!if_any(everything(), is.na)) %>% distinct() 
  })                                                           # remove NA & any duplicates
})

# plot new line segment data
map2(1:2, 2:1, \(j, k) { 
  plt <<- plt %>%                # add lines for x rows, then add lines for y rows
    add_trace(inherit = F, type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines", 
              data = group2NA(df3, names(df3)[j], ordered = names(df3)[k]), # make them segments
              x = ~v1, y = ~v2, z = ~v3, line = list(color = "black"), showlegend = F)
})

plt %>% colorbar(title = "v3") # fix the colorbar title
```

[image]

Let me know if you have questions or if this isn't quite what you're looking for.

Comment: Great answer @Kat! Do you have any idea about this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78156582/taking-screenshots-from-stackoverflow-using-r

Comment: @stats_noob you've got a few answers and a lot of comments. Has your question been answered? I read that a lot of the solutions gave you errors. Let me know.